# Delegated type with factory bot, mutually dependent foreign key issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am trying to figure out how to create Factory objects in the right order so that the delegated class has access to it's parent model. Here are my models:

```
class Alert < ApplicationRecord
  delegated_type :alertable, types: %w[QuotaAlert]
  delegate :trigger_percent, :trigger_percent=, :quota, :quota_public_id, to: :quota_alert
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :alertable, update_only: true
```

```
module Alertable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_one :alert, as: :alertable, touch: true
    delegate :company, :public_id, :channel, to: :alert
```

```
class QuotaAlert < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :trigger_percent
  validates_inclusion_of :trigger_percent, in: 0..1

  belongs_to :quota

  include Alertable
end
```

And my factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :alert do
    company
    channel { 'email' }

    trait :quota_alert_always_trigger do
      before(:create) do |alert|
        alert.alertable = create :quota_alert, trigger_percent: 0
      end
    end
```

However, the delegation of company to alert.company is complaining because it says quota_alert.alert is nil. I think I need to change the ordering of how my factory is creating the objects, but I can't quite figure out the right order.

`QuotaAlert` requires `alert` to be already created to access `alert.company`, however, `alert` can't be created without `QuotaAlert`.

The actual error is: `Module::DelegationError: QuotaAlert#company delegated to alert.company, but alert is nil`

What's the right way to do this?

UPDATE:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :quota_alert do
    quota { create :quota, :with_random_current_count }
    trigger_percent { rand }
  end
end
```

UPDATE 2:
here's the only other factory that gets touched:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :quota do
    limit_amount { rand(5000..10_000) }
    name { Faker::Coffee.blend_name }
    feature
    company
    product
    customer
    subscription

    trait :with_random_current_count do
      after(:create) do |quota|
        quota.set_current_count! rand(1..1000)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what's in the `quota_alert` factory? you don't need a `before` callback, unless you have other reasons for it`association :alertable, factory: :quota_alert`

Comment: @Alex added the quota_alert factory

Comment: I tried a few variations without the create block but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# app/models/*.rb

class Company < ApplicationRecord; end
class Quota < ApplicationRecord; end

class Alert < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company

  delegated_type :alertable, types: %w[QuotaAlert]
  # should delegate to `alertable`; otherwise delegated type setup seems unnecessary
  delegate :trigger_percent, :trigger_percent=, :quota, :quota_public_id, to: :alertable

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :alertable, update_only: true
end

class QuotaAlert < ApplicationRecord
  # include Alertable
  has_one :alert, as: :alertable, touch: true
  delegate :company, :public_id, :channel, to: :alert

  belongs_to :quota

  validates :trigger_percent, presence: true, inclusion: { in: 0..1 }
end
```

```
# spec/factories/alerts.rb

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :quota
  factory :company

  factory :quota_alert do
    quota
    trigger_percent { 0.2 }
  end

  factory :alert do
    company
    channel { 'email' }
    association :alertable, factory: :quota_alert
  end
end
```

```
# spec/fatories_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe "Factories" do
  it { p create(:alert) }
end
```

You're calling `company` somewhere in your factories or in the models before the records get created. Creating an alert does not trigger company delegation by itself.

```
$ rspec spec/factories_spec.rb

Factories
#<Alert id: 1, channel: "email", public_id: nil, company_id: 1, alertable_type: "QuotaAlert", alertable_id: 1>
  example at ./spec/factories_spec.rb:4

Finished in 0.07686 seconds (files took 0.88 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

It might be simpler to create an alert in the console to make sure everything works and then break it down in the factories.

```
>> Alert.create!(alertable: QuotaAlert.create!(trigger_percent: 0.1, quota: Quota.create!), company: Company.create!)
# ...
=> #<Alert:0x00007ff608b5acd8 id: 1, channel: nil, public_id: nil, company_id: 1, alertable_type: "QuotaAlert", alertable_id: 1>
```

Let me know what's missing. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yea that makes sense, I just can't find it. I added the only other factory that gets touched by creating an Alert through the factory to my original question. I also removed basically everything from the test file, put a `binding.pry` in, and am creating an alert in the console, with the same error. Since I'm seeing a delegation error, doesn't that mean the delegation checks to see if `alert.company` is there (you mentioned creating an alert does not trigger company delegation, but creating an alert creates a quota_alert which triggers company delegation).

Comment: I found it! You were right, there was something else calling .company on QuotaAlert before Alert was created. I have another concern on QuotaAlert that does something on `after_commit on: create`. I still want that, but I need to figure out how to "wait" until `Alert` is actually created.

Comment: How would I have an `after_commit on: create` on QuotaAlert that requires a company to be available but the Alert is not yet created?

Comment: Or maybe another way to accomplish it is to have the callback on Alert? I basically want to have a callback on create for when QuotaAlert is created and I want a callback on update for when either QuotaAlert OR Alert is updated. What's the right way to accomplish that?

Comment: I'd have the callback in a model where company association is defined. Depending on what the callback does, it can just schedule a job that would run a few seconds later when everything is committed to database. you can make a service object that could be responsible for creation of alerts and running other logic afterwards.